# Swagger Request custom class as Number

Tags: jax-rs, swagger

I have extended the `BigDecimal` class as a `Premium` class, because I want to add some default behavior (i.e. the `MathContext`). In the created `swagger.json` a `BigDecimal` is presented as:

```
"schema": {
    "type": "number"
}
```

while the `Premium` class is presented as:

```
"schema": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Premium"
}
```

and:

```
"definitions": {
    "Premium": {
        "type": "object"
    }
}
```

How can I annotate the `Premium` class so that it is represented in the `swagger.json` as a `"type": "number"`?

The Premium class looks as follows:

```
public class Premium extends BigDecimal {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final MathContext DEFAULT_MC = MathContext.DECIMAL64;

    public Premium(String val) {
        super(val);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Premium(@JsonProperty BigDecimal bd) {
        this(bd.toString());
    }

    public Premium multiply(Premium val) {
        return new Premium(super.multiply(val));
    }

    public Premium divide(Premium val) {
        return new Premium(super.divide(val, DEFAULT_MC));
    }

    public Premium subtract(Premium val) {
        return new Premium(super.subtract(val));
    }

}
```

And I created a REST service that looks as follows:

```
@Path("/test")
@Api
public class PremiumSvc {

    @POST
    @Path("/pr")
    @ApiOperation("Premium.")
    public Premium doPr(Premium req) {
        return req.subtract(new Premium("0.02"));
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/bd")
    @ApiOperation("BigDecimal.")
    public BigDecimal doBd(BigDecimal req) {
        return req.subtract(new BigDecimal("0.02"));
    }

}
```